# XFAFlattener: How to flatten a dynamic XFA form using pdfxfa-1.0.2 (iText 7) in Java?

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7, xfa

I have a dynamic XFA form. I've filled the form using the `XfaForm.fillXfaForm()` method. The original form is opened in Append Mode. Below is the code to fill the form.

```
private void fillData(String src, String xml, String filledXFAFormdDest, String flattenedPDFDest)
        throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, InterruptedException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    reader.setUnethicalReading(true);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, new PdfWriter(filledXFAFormdDest), new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
    PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
    XfaForm xfa = form.getXfaForm();
    System.out.println(xfa.isXfaPresent());
    xfa.fillXfaForm(new FileInputStream(xml));
    xfa.write(pdfDoc);
    //form.flattenFields(); This throws exception.
    pdfDoc.close();     
}
```

While flattening the form using `XFAFlattener.flatten()`, an exception is thrown. Below is the code to flatten the filled form.

```
private void flattenXFA(String filledXFAFormdDest, String flattenedPDFDest) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filledXFAFormdDest);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(flattenedPDFDest);
    XFAFlattener xfaFlattener = new XFAFlattener();
    xfaFlattener.setFontSettings(new XFAFontSettings().setEmbedExternalFonts(true));
    xfaFlattener.flatten(fis, fos);
    fis.close();
    fos.close();
}
```

The exception reported is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FONTFAMILY
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.font.XFAFontProvider.addFonts(XFAFontProvider.java:117)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.font.XFAFontProvider.<init>(XFAFontProvider.java:56)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.initFlattener(XFAFlattener.java:643)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.flatten(XFAFlattener.java:201)
at com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener.flatten(XFAFlattener.java:396)
at com.mycompany.kitext.kitext.flattenXFA(kitext.java:154)
at com.mycompany.kitext.kitext.main(kitext.java:86)
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm not much aware about the uses of pdfxfa jar. I've gone throught the official documentation of `com.itextpdf.tool.xml.xtra.xfa.XFAFlattener`, but it's barely comprehensive. Also, I've tried the demo of [Understand how XFA Worker flattens your dynamic PDFs to allow for the addition of watermarks, digital signatures or other iText Core functionalities](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfXFA) and realised that the target is surely achievable. This is the [PDF form](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6w278NcMSCrZ1Q1VHc5YzY4UG8/view?usp=sharing) used in the code.

Comment: If you're a customer of iText (and you lust be, since you've access to pdfXFA), you should have access to a support account. Create an issue there and include your input, so Support can help you with your problem. It's most likely related to your input file.

Comment: I'm using the pdfXFA library for under a license for 30-day free trial. Besides, the official support for iText is Stack Overflow. Thus the question. Thanks for the suggestion @SamuelHuylebroeck

Comment: I just want to correct you there, Stackoverflow is not THE official support channel for iText. Our Jira ticketing system is (I'm an iText employee and I've done support, I should know). We monitor Stackoverflow and try to answer when and where we can, but you're not guaranteed to get a reaction from us, in contrast to Jira. That aside, you'll still need to make your input available if you seek an answer, someone can't reproduce your problem without it.

Comment: Please enumerate the steps to create a Jira ticket and submit my work. Provide necessary links too.